# How to write a desktop app that would read/write data to a symbian phone connected to the PC

Tags: c#, .net, mono, symbian, communication

I would like to create a desktop application (preferably in c#, running on .net or mono) that would read/write information (phone book, calendar, calls, text messages, etc.) from/to my connected (usb/bluetooth) symbian phone (SE p990i), but I don't seem to be able to pick up the right keywords to google for it, hence cannot get started.

I considered having a look at some existing OSS application's source code, but couldn't find any. MyPhoneExplorer is freeware, but doesn't provide source code. It requires the Sony-Ericsson communication program to be installed anyway, so assume its code would not be useful on linux.

So please, suggest keywords to search for!

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

It's a couple of years since I worked on Symbian and haven't done much C# so I can't answer directly, but I always found that Eric Bustarret's site at http://www.newlc.com/ was very helpful for all my Symbian problems.

Comment: Thanks! The newlc site seems to be useful, but unfortunately it is not available at the momement, Based on google search on that site what I would need is the connectivity/connect sdk, but all other site search results I get are old (2002-2006), so maybe that won't help.